# Google charts formatter not modifying tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

i am trying to create a line chart using google charts libraries.

The data contains, date (x axis), number (col 1), number (col 2), float (col 3).

I want to display two decimals on the 3rd column tooltip while keeping its y axis 0 to 100, this is my current code (running here https://jsfiddle.net/uqh56hsu/1/):

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Hours');
  data.addColumn('number', 'col1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'col2');
  data.addColumn('number', 'percent');

  data.addRows([
[new Date(1454950800*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454947200*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454943600*1000),2,0,0.00],[new Date(1454940000*1000),24,1,4.17],[new Date(1454936400*1000),12,1,8.33],[new Date(1454932800*1000),64,4,6.25],[new Date(1454929200*1000),176,11,6.25],[new Date(1454925600*1000),142,7,4.93],[new Date(1454922000*1000),114,7,6.14],[new Date(1454918400*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454914800*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454911200*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454907600*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454904000*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454900400*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454896800*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454893200*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454889600*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454886000*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454882400*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454878800*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454875200*1000),0,0,0],[new Date(1454871600*1000),180,10,5.56],      ]);

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
                fractionDigits: 2,
                suffix: '%'
  });
  formatter.format(data, 3);

  var options = {
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
            backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
            colors: ['#ff851b', '#03a9f4', '#8dc859'],
            dateFormat: 'H',
            vAxes:[
                { titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}},
                { titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, format: '#\'%\'', viewWindowMode : 'explicit', viewWindow:{
            max:100,
            min:0
          }}
            ],
            series:[
            {targetAxisIndex:0},
            {targetAxisIndex:0},
            {targetAxisIndex:1}
        ]
  };


  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

I've tried adding the formatter code earlier and later in the code, trying to apply it to other columns, etc, nothing seem to work. The 3rd column tooltip always gets the decimals removed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format` is being set in the `vAxes` option, which was overriding the `formatter`...

Just set the format to --> `format: '#,##0.00\'%\''`

No need for a `formatter` here...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Hours');
  data.addColumn('number', 'col1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'col2');
  data.addColumn('number', 'percent');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(1454950800*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454947200*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454943600*1000),2,0,0.00],
    [new Date(1454940000*1000),24,1,4.17],
    [new Date(1454936400*1000),12,1,8.33],
    [new Date(1454932800*1000),64,4,6.25],
    [new Date(1454929200*1000),176,11,6.25],
    [new Date(1454925600*1000),142,7,4.93],
    [new Date(1454922000*1000),114,7,6.14],
    [new Date(1454918400*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454914800*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454911200*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454907600*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454904000*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454900400*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454896800*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454893200*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454889600*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454886000*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454882400*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454878800*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454875200*1000),0,0,0],
    [new Date(1454871600*1000),180,10,5.56]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
    colors: ['#ff851b', '#03a9f4', '#8dc859'],
    dateFormat: 'H',
    vAxes:[
      {
        titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}
      },
      {
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: '#FF0000'
        },
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100,

        format: '#,##0.00\'%\'',  // set format here -- formatter not needed

        viewWindowMode : 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
          max:100,
          min:0
        }
      }
    ],
    series:[
      {targetAxisIndex:0},
      {targetAxisIndex:0},
      {targetAxisIndex:1}
    ]
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just "fixed" it by using google.visualization.LineChart instead of google.charts.Line, your seems to work too so accepting the answer.